# Modeling repeated cross sectional clustered data

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, generalized-estimating-equations

I have repeated cross sectional data from convenience samples of students nested in schools nested in districts. I have data on student-level behavioral outcomes (binary) and school-level program implementation (continuous). I have student outcome data at time points 1 and 3, and I have school implementation data at time points 1, 2, and 3. I am interested in evaluating the effect of implementation level on student outcomes, essentially for a dose-response.

With this being repeated cross sections and not longitudinal data following the same students, I’m wondering what would be the best statistical approach for the research question? To my understanding, I’m between a mixed effects model and GEE, and I’m leaning towards GEE as I’m most interested in school-level average changes in outcome in response to level of implementation, but I welcome any recommendations/suggestions others with more expertise may have.

Comment: So is the student outcome data at time points 1 and 3 aggregated in some way since you say you are not following the same students ? Can you explain the design in a bit more detail please

Comment: Data from students is collected from a random selection of classrooms in each school so there's no identifying information for any students. I've thought of aggregating the student data to be proportions at the school level (i.e. modeling changes in proportions of students reporting a behavior) but since the samples within a school aren't necessarily representative of the school I've been unsure how to weight responses when aggregating data to the school level.

Comment: Do you know the students' classroom? If so, you could aggregate to the classroom level and then run your model as two levels (classrooms within schools).